# How to find Azure blob container size using azure storage account's Diagnostic settings (classic) version 2 logs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to find Azure blob size or container size using Diagnostic settings (classic) version 2 logs. I have switched on the Diagnostic settings (classic) version 2 logs for a storage account and trying to analyze storage account activity. But is it possible to find blob or a container size over a period of time

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**Diagnostic settings classic 2 Version**:  Two entities are stored in the $MetricsCapacityBlob table each day, **One** summarizing storage account blob and container size details and, **the other** summarizing size details of the $logs container.

Possibility to find blob or a container size over a period of time:
Note that Partition Key : A timestamp in UTC that represents the **starting hour** for metrics, in the following format: YYYYMMddThhmm. Because data is only reported **once** per day, hhmm (hour and minutes) will **always** be 0000. This value is the PartitionKey for all entries in the table. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting?tabs=dotnet)

To enable diagnostic settings you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-metrics?tabs=azure-portal).
Also See [storage analytics metrics/capacity-metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-metrics#capacity-metrics) for more information.

> Note:There are costs associated with examining monitoring data in the
> Azure portal.

---

---

To check Size of a container

**Azure portal :**

In azure portal ,you can see Usage under Blob Service blade.
Open the blob container, select properties under Settings, then click on the Calculate Size button which gives size for each type of blob and also total size of the container.

Please refer these threads if you may want to use **powershell** scripts : [thread 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-billing-size-powershell) ,[thread 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/scripts/storage-blobs-container-calculate-size-powershell)

Comment: There isn't any Calculate Size button anymore.